# Windows Explorer renames files when copying and an existing file is found

Tags: delphi, winapi

Windows Explorer renames files when copying and an existing file is found - do we have access to that facility from Delphi code?

It would be fairly straight forward to write the code to rename the destination filename when using `TFile.Copy()`, but it would be better to use the existing code if available.

Comment: You should try shell functions to copy files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx) is the API to the shell's file copy functionality. Use it to replicate the shell's behaviour. In your case you will need to use [`SetOperationFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775799.aspx) to specify the `FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION` flag:

> Give the item being operated on a new name in a move, copy, or rename operation if an item with the target name already exists.

Comment: Note that `IFileOperation` is only on Vista+. On XP and earlier, use `SHFileOperation()` instead. It also has a `FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION` flag.